# Starting new process by intent. New process runs as part of old process or a new process is created?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am in activity A which is simple Hello world app with a button. I issue this on button Click.

```
Intent intent =new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setUri("http://google.com");
```

Now browser application/process will be invoked,the browser app/process is part of my old app/process or a new process is created?

I think it is not part of my process because even if I do not have `Uses internet permission`, I can still access internet. Thus new activity runs as part of new process.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case System allocates memory for "Browser" process but Browser's `Activity` is added to your Task, to your Task's BackStack, to be more correctly.

Comment: So a task can have activities with different permissions?(I did not give internet access permission to my app but I can still access internet)  That does not sound right to me. Of course I could be wrong. I just want to know more.

Comment: Yes you right. Permissions are specified for a single application (single process) and you may use this wonderful feature to integrate your app with other apps (Browser in your case). Security is asured by using `intent-filters` which prevent application from sending there malicious data by intent.

Comment: Thanks for answering, If the other app had more than one activity, only the activity whose intent filter matched would become part of my application's task or all the activities of that application?

Answer (score 2):

Applications need to be signed with the same key to run in the same process.
I guess your application is not signed with the same key as the browser-app, so it's safe to say they do not run in the same process.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html

> You can also set android:process so that components of different applications run in the same process—provided that the applications share the same Linux user ID and are signed with the same certificates.

Comment: Hey, nice answer. +1, the only reason I did not mark your answer as accepted is because accepted answer did more than just confirm my understanding. I was told how and why it works like that. You are new to SO, I hope you enjoy and help the community with your knowledge.

Comment: Thnx for the +1 :-) I use SO a lot so I thought it was time to return the favour. I agree, the other answer is better, because it explains the BackStack.